# Chinese Remainder Theorem in a strange configuration

Tags: rsa

Normally, the chinese theorem looks like this:$$
x = a_1 \bmod n_1\\
x = a_2 \bmod n_2\\
x = a_3 \bmod n_3$$
but what to do if in my situation it looks like this:$$
c_1 = x^e \bmod n_1\\
c_2 = x^e \bmod n_2\\
c_3 = x^e \bmod n_3$$

I know $c_1$, $c_2$, $c_3$, $e$, $n_1$, $n_2$ and $n_3$. So how do I find $x$?

Comment: This is the RSA broadcast attack, also known as [Håstad’s broadcast attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%27s_attack#H%C3%A5stad's_broadcast_attack). We have [several questions about that](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Brsa%5D+Håstad+broadcast+%5Battack%5D). It assumes the same message is encrypted with textbook RSA _without random padding_ (a big no-no). Also it's simple form works only up to some value of $e$ (related to the number of ciphertexts, size of message and muduli), but one should not rely on the later.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same format. You can arrange the equations as $x^e \equiv c_i $ $mod$ $n_i $ by swapping sides, then you can apply Chinese Remainder Theorem to find the value of $x^e \equiv C $ $mod$ $n_1$$n_2$$n_3$. After that, you may try the cube root attack [if public exponent $(e)$ is a small value.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/55941/breaking-rsa-using-chinese-remainder-theorem/55944#55944)

Answer (score 1):

NB_1907 gave the answer for small $e$ (3 if you are given three equations).

Now, let us look at the case where $e$ is potentially large.

In that case, what you end up needing to do is convert it into a series of conventional equivalences, that is:

From $c_1 = x^e \bmod n_1$, you find the value of $x \bmod n_1$ that satisfices it; if $e$ and $n_1$ are relatively prime, the sole value is $n_1 = c_1^{e^-1 \bmod \phi(n_1)}$ [1].

From $c_2 = x^e \bmod n_2$, you similarly find the value of $x \bmod n_2$

From $c_3 = x^e \bmod n_3$, you similarly find the value of $x \bmod n_3$.

From $x \bmod n_1, x \bmod n_2, x \bmod n_3$, you use the CRT conventionally to recover $x \bmod \text{lcm}( n_1, n_2, n_3 )$ (assuming, of course, if it exists)

Now, this is not a great help if you're giving three RSA encryptions of the same value (using the same exponent); it would be easier just to break one of the RSA public keys (rather than all three).  However it might be of use if you're given a smaller problem, where the $x$ value might be larger than any of the moduli.

---

[1]: To determine $\phi(n_1)$, you'll need to factor $n_1$ as a substep.

Comment: @fgrieu: in any case, any problem involving factoring or exponentiation by public exponents tend to be labeled 'RSA'; hence I wouldn't necessarily deduce a great deal from that labelling.

Comment: I deleted earlier obsolete comments. Still I think we need $x\bmod n_1\;=\;{c_1}^{e^{-1}\bmod \phi(n_1)}\bmod n_1$ where there is now $n_1 = c_1^{e^-1 \bmod \phi(n_1)}$.